# How to format a DateTime in PowerShell

Tags: datetime, powershell

I can format the [`Get-Date`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849887.aspx) cmdlet no problem like this:

```
$date = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"
```

But once I've got [a date](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in a variable, how do I format it? The statement below

```
$dateStr = $date -format "yyyMMdd"
```

returns this error:

> "You must provide a value expression
>   on the right-hand side of the '-f'
>   operator"

Comment: I actually wished this syntax worked. `$date -format "yyyMMdd"` is much more intuitive for formatting a single object than `'{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $date`.

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell has an `-f` operator (with the syntax as shown in the accepted answer), but no `-format` operator. The error message is complaining about `ormat` not being a valid RHS operand, but note that recent PowerShell versions actually emit a different, more helpful error message: `Unexpected token '-format' in expression or statement`

Comment: @orad your comment does vastly more to explain the "{0:...}" syntax boilerplate than the top+accepted answer that suggests it. Thank you. (Your comment tells us that it's a special case of something that supports multiple things being formatted at once, which in turn lets us realize that we're looking at something far more general than just syntactic sugar for `.ToString(...)`... and that, combined with enough programming experience, we can guess that the format strings use zero-indexed references to the objects being interpolated, and use {} to wrap placeholders.)

Answer (score 320, accepted):

The same as you would in [.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings):

```
$DateStr = $Date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Or:

```
$DateStr = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $Date
```

Note that you can have a format string that gets multiple objects. For example:

```
'From {0:M/d/yyyy} to {1:M/d/yyyy}' -f $Date, $Date.AddDays(7)
```

Comment: Results in: `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.`

Comment: @Langdon - Assuming you are using the form $Date.ToString(...) then that error is because your $Date variable contains Null. You'll need to make sure you've actually assigned a DateTime value to it before calling ToString. ... The second form (using the -f operator) appears to tolerate nulls and will simply output an empty string.

Comment: I want to +1 but the totally cryptic appearance of "0:" and wrapping "{...}" with no explanation is really offputting for me. Why are they there? what are they saying to PowerShell or to the "-f" operator or to [...]?

Comment: @mtraceur I updated the answer to clarify formatting objects using multiple format tokens.

Answer (score 57):

A simple and nice way is:

`$time = (Get-Date).ToString("yyyy:MM:dd")`

Comment: This was the only approach that didn't throw a null-valued expression error for me. Thanks.

Comment: Ummm, doesn't this return the date formatted as a 24-hour  time or am I being too US-Centric???

Comment: It’s in any format you specify. Regardless of your place of origin.

Comment: This is a better answer as the others had issues for me

Answer (score 35):

The question is answered, but there is some more information missing:

**Variable vs. Cmdlet**

You have a value in the `$Date` variable and the `-f` operator does work in this form: `'format string' -f values`. If you call `Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd"` you call a [cmdlet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell#Comparison_of_cmdlets_with_similar_commands) with some parameters. The value "yyyyMMdd" is the value for parameter `Format` (try `help Get-Date -param Format`).

**`-f` operator**

There are plenty of format strings. Look at least at [part1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kathykam/net-format-string-101) and [part2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kathykam/net-format-string-102-datetime-format-string). She uses `string.Format('format string', values')`. Think of it as `'format-string' -f values`, because the `-f` operator works very similarly as `string.Format` method (although there are some differences (for more information look at question at Stack Overflow: *[How **exactly** does the RHS of PowerShell's -f operator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1872146)*).

Comment: What he is saying is that the -Format parameter causes Get-DateTime to return a string, not a DateTime object. So your variable $Date can no longer be formatted as expected. I REALLY wish the the -Format parameter would simply change the default behavior of a particular DateTime object's ToString method. Then it would work as you had expected.

Comment: Either put examples in or append your comments to the selected answer. IMO

Answer (score 30):

A very convenient -- but probably not all too efficient -- solution is to use the member function [`GetDateTimeFormats()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.getdatetimeformats?view=netframework-4.7.2),

```
$d = Get-Date
$d.GetDateTimeFormats()
```

This outputs a large string-array of formatting styles for the date-value. You can then pick one of the elements of the array via the `[]`-operator, e.g.,

```
PS C:\> $d.GetDateTimeFormats()[12]
Dienstag, 29. November 2016 19.14
```

Comment: I like this answer because it encourages us to explore possibilities.

Answer (score 23):

One thing you could do is:

```
$date.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: Thanks I did this - bugs me that -format doesn't work though.

Answer (score 13):

Do this if you absolutely need to use the `-Format` option:

```
$dateStr = Get-Date $date -Format "yyyMMdd"
```

However

```
$dateStr = $date.toString('yyyMMdd')
```

is probably more efficient.. :)

Comment: `$dateStr = (Get-Date $date -Format "yyyMMdd")` results in an object type that is different from a datetime object.  Try playing around with this `$dateStr = [datetime](Get-Date $date -Format "yyyMMdd")`  You'll see the difference right away.

Comment: Well, yeah.. It's a String, that's why I named it dateStr.. :) OP was trying to format a date object to a String.

Answer (score 7):

For anyone trying to format the current date **for use in an HTTP header** use the "r" format (short for RFC1123) but beware the caveat...

```
PS C:\Users\Me> (get-date).toString("r")
Thu, 16 May 2019 09:20:13 GMT
PS C:\Users\Me> get-date -format r
Thu, 16 May 2019 09:21:01 GMT
PS C:\Users\Me> (get-date).ToUniversalTime().toString("r")
Thu, 16 May 2019 16:21:37 GMT
```

I.e. Don't forget to use "ToUniversalTime()"

Comment: Use this with "o" for "xml" style datetimes

Answer (score 7):

I needed the time and a slight variation on format.  This works great for my purposes:

```
$((get-date).ToLocalTime()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss")
```

> 2019-08-16 215757

According to @mklement0 in comments, this should yield the same result:

```
(get-date).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HHmmss")
```

Answer (score 6):

If you got here to use this in `cmd.exe` (in a batch file):

```
powershell -Command (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Answer (score 5):

Very informative [answer from @stej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249861/5571827), but here is a short answer:
Among [other options](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730954.aspx), you have **3 simple options** to format [System.DateTime] stored in a variable:

1. Pass the variable to the [Get-Date cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date):
   `Get-Date -Format "HH:mm" $date`
2. Use [toString() method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx):
   `$date.ToString("HH:mm")`
3. Use [Composite formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting):
   `"{0:HH:mm}" -f $date`

Answer (score 2):

**Format Date Time to your Output Needs**

If you want to format the date and assign the string to a variable.
I have combined both PowerShell and .NET to provide the flexibility.

```
    $oDate = '{0}' -f ([system.string]::format('{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}',(Get-Date)))
```

**How this Works**

- PowerShell Operator - '{0}' -f (.....)
- .NET Notation - [system.string]::format('*customformat*',*InputObject*)
- Customised Format by combining PowerShell with .NET - '{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}'
- Input Object provided by PowerShell cmdlet - (Get-Date)
- Stored in the PowerShell variable - $oDate

**Example**

If the date and time when run was Monday, 5 July 2021 5:45:22 PM (Format '{0:F}').

- $oDate = 20210705174522

**Using the Code**

You can customise the the string to meet your requirements by modifying 'yyyMMddHHmmss' using the [Microsoft .NET Custom Date Time Notation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: why not just?
[string]$oDate = '([system.string]::format('{0:yyyyMMddHHmmss}',(Get-Date)))

Answer (score 0):

You could just use this to select the format you want and then past it wherever it is needed.

```
$DTFormats = (Get-Date).GetDateTimeFormats()
$Formats = @()
$i=0
While ($i -lt $DTFormats.Count){
    $row = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'IndexNumber' = $i
        'DateTime Format' = $DTFormats[$i]
    }
    $Formats += $row
    $i++
}

$DTSelection = ($Formats | Out-GridView -OutputMode Single -Title 'Select DateTime Format').IndexNumber
$MyDTFormat = "(Get-Date).GetDateTimeFormats()[$DTSelection]"
Write-Host " "
Write-Host " Use the following code snippet to get the DateTime format you selected:"
Write-Host "    $MyDTFormat" -ForegroundColor Green
Write-Host " "
$MyDTFormat | Clip
Write-Host " The code snippet has been copied to your clipboard. Paste snippet where needed."
```

Answer (score 0):

I converted my dueDate string to a datetime then formatted it.

```
 [Datetime]::ParseExact($dueDate,'MM/dd/yyyy H:mm:ss',$null).ToString('MM/dd/yyyy')
```