# PowerShell Get-Date into an Array

Tags: date, powershell, if-statement

I'm trying to get three different Timestamps from PowerShell as shown below.  I've worked out the various commands using `GET-DATE` to accomplish this but I'm not sure how to make a loop in PowerShell work with `GET-DATE` and increment `GET-DATE` with the formatting needed.

What I've got so far is below.

```psh
"1/26/2015 1:00 AM"
"2015-01-26"
"Sunday"
((Get-Date -Format "M/dd/yyyy") + " " + "1:00 am").ToUpper()
(Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd")
(Get-Date).DayOfWeek
for ($i = 0; $i -lt 7; $i++)
 {
$d = ((Get-Date -Format "M/dd/yyyy").AddDays($i))
$d
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

So, there's a couple things here...

First, you are over complicating things. To see if it is Monday simply do:

```
If((Get-Date).DayOfWeek -eq "Monday"){
    "It is Monday, executing script"
}Else{
    "Not Monday! Abort!"
}
```

So getting back to what you asked for... an array with the days of the week in it. This is where `[Enum]` comes in real handy. You already have used `[DayOfWeek]` to cast "Monday" as an actual day object not just a string, but you want all of the days from that type. To do that you can use `[Enum]`'s `getvalues()` method as such:

```
$Days = [Enum]::GetValues([DayOfWeek])
```

Now, I think I'll try and guess what you were getting at, trying to get the next Monday's date if the script is not run on a Monday. If you want the previous Monday just change the `$i++` to `$i--` in the following code:

```
If((Get-Date).DayOfWeek -ne "Monday"){
    $i=0
    While((get-date).AddDays($i).DayOfWeek -ne "Monday"){$i++}
    "The next valid day to run this script is $((get-date).AddDays($i).ToShortDateString())."
}Else{
    Do Stuff Here
}
```

Comment: Thank you @TheMadTechnician, the IF statement is much better.  Now, for the script goal:  I'm writing a script to automate creating tickets.  The script is run on Monday and needs to create three variables in various formats.  For example
`My-Ticket -date "1/26/2015 1:00 AM" -day "2015-01-26" -dayofweek "Monday"`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was close.  Here's what clued me in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2249639/4317867 and I apologize for my horrible skills at writing up questions!

Ended up doing:

```psh
for ($i = 1; $i -le 7; $i++)
{
 $d = ((Get-Date).AddDays($i))
 $d2 = $d.ToString("M/dd/yyyy")
 $d2
}
```

Output is:

```
1/28/2015
1/29/2015
1/30/2015
1/31/2015
2/01/2015
2/02/2015
2/03/2015
```