# Powershell convert date in variable to different date format

Tags: powershell-4.0

My script pulls the software installation date and puts it into $obj.InstallDate.
The value returned is in the format of 20131227. I want to convert this to December 27, 2013 but can't get this to work.

The Get-Date in powershell doesn't work for me. What do I need to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249619/how-to-format-a-datetime-in-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this
    $DateValue = 20131228

```
Get-Date -Year $DateValue.ToString().Substring(0,4) -Month $DateValue.ToString().Substring(4,2) -Day $DateValue.ToString().Substring(6,2) -Format "MMMM dd, yyyy"
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thanks