# Convert Date variable into particular format in Powershell

Tags: powershell, datetime

Get-Date -format yyyy/M/d works in PS1 but it doesnt work with variable date like, 
$date -format yyyy/M/d. 
It prompts an error - Unexpected token in expression or statement.

How can I make the $date variable work.

Thanks, 
A curious mind!

Comment: `Get-Date $date -format yyyy/M/d`

Comment: alternative option just because `([datetime]$date).tostring('yyyy/MM/dd')`

Answer (score 4):

You can recreate an object with Get-Date:

```
Get-Date $date -format yyyy/M/d
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `($date).ToString('yyyy/M/d')`

Editing to say you can pipe the `$date` variable to `Get-Member` in order to reveal the available methods.  Then we can search for formatting a DateTime string in PowerShell [For example, this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249619/how-to-format-a-datetime-in-powershell)

```
$date | GM
TypeName: System.DateTime
ToString             Method         
 string ToString(), string ToString(string format), 
 string ToString(System.IFormatProvider provider), ...
```