# Time format in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, time, restore

I like to have the following PowerShell script output without the date part from the table.

---

```
10/21/2017 16:49 | Systrax Restore Point
```

Currently the output is:

```
@{Date=10/21/2017 12:40} | Systrax Auto Restore Point
```

This is part of my script:

```
$creationtime = Get-ComputerRestorePoint | Select-Object @{Label="Date"; Expression={"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}" -f $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationTime)}}
$restorepoint = (Get-ComputerRestorePoint).Description
if ($restorepoint -eq $null){
    Enable-ComputerRestore -Drive "C:\"
    Checkpoint-Computer "Systrax Auto Restore Point"
    Write-Host "No restore points, Auto Creating..."
    Exit 1010
}
else {
    Write-Host "$creationtime | $restorepoint"
    Exit 0
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Given a DateTime object, how do I get an ISO 8601 date in string format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114983/given-a-datetime-object-how-do-i-get-an-iso-8601-date-in-string-format)

Comment: Another duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249619/how-to-format-a-datetime-in-powershell, among many many others. Please search before asking. Relevant documentation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings (Besides, `mm/dd/yyyy` is not a sensible date format, avoid.)

Comment: got it
(Get-ComputerRestorePoint).CreationTime, (Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')

But then its still outputting the original timeformat

20171021104047.441419-000
2017-10-21

Comment: im a total noob and just looking for someone who might wanne make this script correct for me, willing to do some donation

Comment: Please see my [answer on Date-Time formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51898787/5571827).
HTH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-f` format operator to format the resulting `DateTime` object in your calculated property:

```
... |Format-Table @{Label="Date"; Expression={"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}" -f $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationTime)}}
```

Another option is calling `ToString()` on the object:

```
... |Format-Table @{Label="Date"; Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationTime).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")}}
```

Or you can have `Get-Date` do it for you:

```
... |Format-Table @{Label="Date"; Expression={$_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationTime) |Get-Date -Format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"}}
```

Comment: Thank you but it didnt worked: still getting the time in unreadable format
20171021104047.441419-000
``
`(Get-ComputerRestorePoint).CreationTime | Format-Table @{Label="Date"; Expression={"{0:MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm}" -f $_.ConvertToDateTime($_.CreationTime)}}`

Comment: `Get-ComputerRestorePoint | Format-Table ...`, not `(Get-ComputerRestorePoint).CreationTime | ...`

Comment: ill be damned, cool this cause the info is in the table, got it, but i still have a table and i want the outplain plain is this even possible? ty

Comment: Replace `Format-Table` with `Select-Object` if you want to work with the resulting object further

Comment: maybe something with write-host, select second/thirs row from previous output, is this possible? if you look at the OP you might get an idea what i really want