# Substract a date with Powershell

Tags: powershell

Using Powershell I need to get a date in the "yyyyMMdd" format.
I can use $Date_Today = Get-Date -format "yyyyMMdd" and it works corerctly.

Now I need to get the date, a day ago:

```
(Get-Date).adddays(-1)
```

But If I need to get the date , a day ago in the same format I get an error:

```
((Get-Date).adddays(-1)) -format "yyyyMMdd"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a DateTime in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249619/how-to-format-a-datetime-in-powershell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `.ToString()` function to get the desired result:

```
(Get-Date).adddays(-1).ToString("yyyyMMdd")
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks Toby