# Using Get-IntuneManagedDevice to get devices synced today

Tags: powershell, date, time, microsoft-graph-api, intune

I'm trying to get a list of serial numbers of devices via PowerShell with the below command where the Serial Number isn't blank and the DeviceName and ManagedDeviceName don't have "MOB-" in them. I can do this with the below command:

```
Get-IntuneManagedDevice -filter "manufacturer eq 'Apple'" | Get-MSGraphAllPages | Where-Object -Property issupervised -eq True | Where-object { $_.devicename -notlike "*MOB-*" -or $_.manageddevicename -notlike "*MOB*" -and $_.serialnumber -ne $Null -and $_.serialnumber -ne ""} | Select serialnumber
```

That works well enough. But what I also want to do is only show the devices where the "lastsyncdatetime" is today. I've tried doing the below (As an example of todays date) but that doesn't return anything at all:

```
Get-IntuneManagedDevice -filter "manufacturer eq 'Apple'" | Get-MSGraphAllPages | Where-Object -Property issupervised -eq True | Where-object { $_.devicename -notlike "*MOB-*" -or $_.manageddevicename -notlike "*MOB*" -and $_.serialnumber -ne $Null -and $_.serialnumber -ne "" -and $_.lastsyncdatetime -like "*23/06/2023*"} | Select serialnumber
```

For reference, if I select the "lastsyncdatetime" attribute, the date is in the format of **DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM:SS**. Even if I don't do an asterisk and search for the exact date and time, it still doesn't show the entry.

Comment: @ravenspoint my bad, have now edited.

Comment: I suspect `LastSyncDateTime` is a `DateTime` object not a `string`, Use `Get-Member` to confirm. Formatting examples here [How to format a DateTime in PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249619/how-to-format-a-datetime-in-powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Get-IntuneManagedDevice | Get-MSGraphAllPages | where {$_.lastSyncDateTime -ge "$((get-date).adddays(-1))"} | Select deviceName,lastSyncDateTime,userDisplayName | sort lastSyncDateTime

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).