# Make select -unique on arraylist return arraylist instead of string

Tags: powershell

I have three arraylists in below class. I want to keep them unique. However if there's only one item (string) in the arraylist and you use select -unique (or any other method to achieve this) it will return the string instead of a list of strings. Surrounding it with @() also doesn't work because that transforms it to an array instead of an arraylist, which I can't add stuff to.

Any suggestions that are still performant? I tried HashSets before but somehow had horrible experiences with those. See my previous post for that.. [Post on hashset issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880295/powershell-hashset-members-wrongly-cast-to-hashset?noredirect=1#comment104063826_58880295)

Code below:

```
Class OrgUnit
{
    [String]$name
    $parents
    $children
    $members


    OrgUnit($name){
        $this.name = $name
        $this.parents = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $this.children = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $this.members = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
    }

    addChild($child){
        # > $null to supress output
        $tmp = $this.children.Add($child)
        $this.children = $this.children | select -Unique
    }

    addParent($parent){
        # > $null to supress output
        $tmp = $this.parents.Add($parent) 
        $this.parents = $this.parents | select -Unique
    }

    addMember($member){
        # > $null to supress output
        $tmp = $this.members.Add($member)
        $this.members = $this.members | select -Unique
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding a new item to the array, then selecting unique items from it, and reassingning it every time you add a member. This is extremely inefficient, maybe try the following instead:

```
if (-not $this.parents.Contains($parent)) {
  $this.parents.Add($parent) | out-null
}
```

Would be much faster even with least efficient output supressing by out-null.

Comment: I assume the `$tmp` is used to get rid of the message after the `.Add()`.

Comment: I feel almost embarrassed not doing the last solution.. I did it differently twice before and then I started tunnelvisioning which led me to doing it the way as in the first post. But yes that approach seems to be the obvious answer. THANK YOU! :) Also the one with the hashset led me to issues as in the post I linked to.

Comment: @Spyral: take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260125/whats-the-better-cleaner-way-to-ignore-output-in-powershell). It seems there is no 100% right / wrong :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check with `.Contains()` if the item is already added, so you don't have to eliminate duplicates with `Select-Object -Unique` afterwards all the time.

```
if (-not $this.children.Contains($child))
{
    [System.Void]($this.children.Add($child))
}
```

Comment: Nicely done (+1). As an aside: a syntactically simpler output-suppression technique is to use `$null = ...` - that way you don't need the `(...)`; to wit: `$null = $this.children.Add($child)`

Answer (score 1):

As has been pointed out, **it's worth changing your approach due to its inefficiency**:

Instead of blindly appending and then possibly removing the new element if it turns out to be duplicate with `Select-Object -Unique`, use a *test* to decide whether an element needs to be appended or is already present.

[Patrick's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58933066/45375) is a straightforward implementation of this optimized approach that will greatly speed up your code and should perform acceptably unless the array lists get very large.

As a side effect of this optimization - because the array lists are only ever modified in-place with `.Add()` - your original problem goes away.

---

**To answer the question as asked**:

Simply ***type-constrain* your (member) variables** if you want them to retain a given type even during later assignments.

That is, just as you did with `$name`, place the type you want the member to be constrained to the left of the member variable declarations:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $parents
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $children
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $members
```

However, that will initialize these member variables to `$null`, which means you won't be able to just call `.Add()` in your `.add*()` methods; therefore, construct an (initially empty) instance as part of the declaration:

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $parents =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $children = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $members =  [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()
```

Also, you *do* have to use `@(...)` around your `Select-Object -Unique` pipeline; while that indeed outputs an *array* (type `[object[]]`), the type constraint causes that array to be converted to a `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` instance, as explained below.

<sup>The need for `@(...)` is somewhat surprising - see bottom section.</sup>

**Notes on type constraints**:

- If you assign a value that isn't already of the type that the variable is constrained to, PowerShell attempts to *convert* it to that type; **you can think of it as implicitly performing a *cast* to the constraining type on every assignment**:

  - This can *fail*, if the assigned value simply isn't convertible; PowerShell's type conversions are generally very flexible, however.
  - In the case of collection-like types such as `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`, any other collection-like type can be assigned, such as the `[object[]]` arrays returned by `@(...)` (PowerShell's [array-subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators#array-subexpression-operator--)). Note that, of necessity, this involves constructing a *new* `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` every time, which becomes, loosely speaking, a shallow clone of the input collection.
  - Pitfalls re assigning `$null`:

    - If the constraining type is a *value type* (if its `.IsValueType` property reports `$true`), assigning `$null` will result in the type's *default value*; e.g., after executing 
      `[int] $i = 42; $i = $null`, `$i` isn't `$null`, it is `0`.
    - If the constraining type is a *reference type* (such as `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`), assigning `$null` will truly store `$null` in the variable, though later attempts to assign non-null values will again result in conversion to the constraining type.
- In essence, this is the same technique used in *parameter* variables, and can also be used in *regular* variables.

  - With *regular* variables (local variables in a function or script), you *must* also initialize the variable in order for the type constraint to work (for the variable to even be created); e.g.:
    `[System.Collections.ArrayList] $alist = 1, 2`

**Applied to a simplified version of your code**:

```
Class OrgUnit
{

  [string] $name
  # Type-constrain $children too, just like $name above, and initialize
  # with an (initially empty) instance.
  [System.Collections.ArrayList] $children = [System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()

  addChild($child){
    # Add a new element.
    # Note the $null = ... to suppress the output from the .Add() method.
    $null = $this.children.Add($child)

    # (As noted, this approach is inefficient.)
    # Note the required @(...) around the RHS (see notes in the last section).
    # Due to its type constraint, $this.children remains a [System.Collections.ArrayList] (a new instance is created from the
    # [object[]] array that @(...) outputs).
    $this.children = @($this.children | Select-Object -Unique)
  }

}
```

With the type constraint in place, the `.children` property now remains a `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`:

```
PS> $ou = [OrgUnit]::new(); $ou.addChild(1); $ou.children.GetType().Name
ArrayList   # Proof that $children retained its type identity.
```

---

Note: **The need for `@(...)`** - to ensure an array-valued assignment value in order to successfully convert to `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` - is **somewhat surprising**, given that the following works with the similar *generic* list type, `[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]`:

```
# OK: A scalar (single-object) input results in a 1-element list.
[System.Collections.Generic.List[object]] $list = 'one'
```

By contrast, this does *not* work with `[System.Collections.ArrayList]`:

```
# !! FAILS with a scalar (single object)
# Error message: Cannot convert the "one" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Collections.ArrayList".
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $list = 'one'

# OK
# Forcing the RHS to an array ([object[]]) fixes the problem.
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $list = @('one')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Collections

Class OrgUnit
{
    [String]$name
    $parents
    $children
    $members


    OrgUnit($name){
        $this.name = $name
        $this.parents  = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
        $this.children = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
        $this.members  = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
    }

    addChild($child){
        # > $null to supress output
        $tmp = $this.children.Add($child)
        $this.children = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]@($this.children | select -Unique)
    }

    addParent($parent){
        # > $null to supress output
        $tmp = $this.parents.Add($parent) 
        $this.parents = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]@($this.parents | select -Unique)
    }

    addMember($member){
        # > $null to supress output
        $tmp = $this.members.Add($member)
        $this.members = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]@($this.members | select -Unique)
    }
}
```