# Using array in headers in Invoke-RestMethod

Tags: powershell, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to use Cosmos DB REST API using Invoke-RestMethod
 method .My headers are as below

```
  'Authorization' = $authToken
  'x-ms-date' =  $UTCTimeNow
  'x-ms-version' = '2017-02-22'
  'x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey' = @($partitonKey)
}
```

response received is Partition key System.String[] is invalid. It seems Powershell is not sending x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey as an array.Is there a way to pass array in headers in powershell web request

Comment: Try an [anary comma operator `,`](https://learn.microsoft.com/owershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7#comma-operator-): `'x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey' = ,$partitonKey`, see also: [Why is a leading comma required when creating an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42772083/1701026)

Comment: Please try to `'x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey' = '["<partitonKey vaule>"]'`

Comment: @iRon, Jim Xu Thanks for replying. I have tried both approaches and it didn't worked. So for me headers is a C# dictionary and Invoke-RestMethod method is somehow converting it into JSON internally itself. Hence changing the array type to string or this manual casting only make typecasting issues

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and/or more detials, see also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: From what I can tell, you are going to need `-ContentType 'application/json'` on your POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
'x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey' = '[' + ($partitonKey) + ']'
```

Source and more details: https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB/blob/e2da6d6d20c798fde0489bb0d751469f11b265fe/src/lib/documents/Format-CosmosDbDocumentPartitionKey.ps1

Comment: Thanks for replying, but it seems the example you shared is limited to PlagueHO's CosmosDB API while I am trying to use existing Cosmos DB REST API by using Invoke-RestMethod generic method calling REST endpoint

Comment: It's an implementation of CosmosDB REST API. There's no such thing as PlagueHO Cosmos DB. From this link: https://github.com/PlagueHO/CosmosDB - `This PowerShell module provides cmdlets for working with Azure Cosmos DB.`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work, but seems to me this should just work:

```
[array]$partitonKey = "test"
$headers = @{}
$headers.Add('x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey', $partitonKey)
$headers
```

When you convert the above to JSON, the output is:

```
{
    "x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey":  [
                                         "test"
                                     ]
}
```

Which is an array within the Key "x-ms-documentdb-partitionkey".

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for help, this is the first thing I tried. And I check ConvertTo-Json for dictionary gives above result only, but somehow it seems Invoke-RestMethod does not works this way