# Is there a trick to never have to worry about a dangling comma in PowerShell param statements?

Tags: powershell, parameters, syntax-error

```
param (

                [string]$ComputerName="Server01",
                [string[]]$SEARCHTERMS=@("Unifi","Edge"),
                [string]$IPAddress='10.11.12.243',   #Dangling comma that i never see.
)
```

There must be a ... AND 1=1; trick like what is commonly done in sql statements to move parameters around without much thought.

Comment: I don't understand what you're are asking. Are you looking to run a powershell script even with syntactic errors? also you wouldn't have such syntax problems with a proper code editor (Visual Studio Code) and the powershell preview extension.

Answer (score 3):

No, I think there is *no* trick that avoids this syntax error.

The only consolation is that if you use  [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), combined with its [PowerShell extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.PowerShell), you get near-instantaneous visual feedback that there's a syntax problem:

[image: screenshot with highlighted syntax error]

The `PROBLEMS` tab in the panel view (toggle with <kbd>Ctrl-J</kbd>) states the specific problem:
`Missing expression after ','.`

---

Making PowerShell *tolerant* of an extraneous (dangling) `,` after the last parameter declaration inside `param(...)` - so as to make reordering parameter declarations less painful - has been officially suggested in the past - by a former core member of the PowerShell team, no less - but the suggestion was *declined*:

- See (declined) [GitHub issue #8873](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8873), which also mentions *not requiring `,` separators at all* as a potential enhancement, analogous to how you can place elements inside [`@(...)`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) on separate lines to form array elements, without the need for a(nother) separator.

Comment: Yes!  It is exaclty like `@(arraymembers on separate lines) ` .   Generally, the fewer characters on the screen make code more readable.    I end up hacking on many different OSs and machines, so cant / dont want to install vsCode everywhere.  Interesting history.   Maybe it has something to do with using the comma to force an @(ARRAY) to pass by reference instead of copying as talked about [Braces, comma, parameter method call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39745848/braces-comma-parameter-method-call)

Comment: @rjt, understood re not wanting to install VSCode. In the linked post, `,` is actually an _operator_ (the [array constructor operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#comma-operator-)), which is unrelated to the parse-time-only syntactic use of `,` inside the `param(...)` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
param (

     [string]$ComputerName="Server01",
     [string[]]$SEARCHTERMS=@("Unifi","Edge"),
     [string]$IPAddress='10.11.12.243', #Dangling comma that i never see.
     [string]$DumbCommas='Extra Param to Protect me from commas.'
)
```

Needs a shorter variable name, but it will do.

Comment: Note that this has several unwanted side effects: It makes your function accept an extra argument (which matters if you use `[CmdletBinding()]` to prevent unbound arguments). The extra parameter shows up with `Get-Help` / `Get-Command -Syntax`. The extra parameter shows up in tab completion. You could mitigate these problems somewhat (preventing positional binding to your dummy parameter, giving it a name that prevents _named_ binding), but doing so requires so much extra effort that it defeats your original intent.